# Can SSL certificate having additional alternative name be used on two hosts?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

having an SSL certificate issued for the host `hostname111.mydomain.com` and with configured the alternative name `hostname222.mydomain.com`, is it possible to install the certificate on **two different** hosts? Would the certificate be verified properly in either case?

Thank you.

Comment: With my letsencrypt cert, i have 2 subdomains on different hosts. Infact originally they were on the same and eventually got moved. I just reran certbot with that domain request on the new machine and i was good to go.

Comment: In short: a certificate can be used on multiple servers as long as it matches the domain. It does not matter if wildcard, multiple SAN etc